# I wanted to add overflow-y scroll to CSS on basis of number of characters in task. Is this possible using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

```
<div data-bind="text: title, CSS: {quesHolder: true}"></div>
```

In CSS File

```
 .quesHolder{
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

Now I dont want the disabled scroll to come into view when content in my div is small in length.
However I need scroll only when needed.
Is there anyway to calculate number of characters displayed in div?
Does knockout has some special feature for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the scroll bar to appear when needed, then you can do this in CSS using:

```
.quesHolder{
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Info on MDN: [Overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)